# Rename pdf files and create & move files basis filename

Tags: pdf, cmd

I have 5000 `.pdf` files which I have to rename and to move into newly created folders, whose names are based on the original file names.

For example: original name is `crf--aaa--208912--2089120010`.

The folder name should be `208912` and the file name `2089120010`.

Please help with the process to do so.

Comment: Helping implies that you do something on your own, so please share what you have tried so far and describe precisely where you are stuck! Regard that StackOverflow is not a free code writing service!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to thy the following code snippet:

```cmd
rem // Change to directory containing the files:
pushd "D:\Data" && (
    rem // Retrieve matching files and iterate through them:
    for /F "delims=" %%F in ('dir /B /A:-D "*--*--*--*.pdf"') do (
        rem // Store name of currently iterated file:
        set "NAME=%%F"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        rem /* Split name into tokens separated by `--`; since `for /F` uses characters
        rem    as delimiters but not strings, `--` is replaced by `|` intermittently: */
        for /F "tokens=3* delims=|" %%I in ("!NAME:--=|!") do (
            endlocal
            rem // Create sub-directory:
            mkdir "%%I"
            rem // Rename and move file:
            move "%%F" "%%I\%%J"
        )
        endlocal
    )
    rem // Restore previous working directory:
    popd
)
```